# Why doesn't ubuntu install applications similar to mac?

Tags: installation, mac, apple

I used a macbook a little while ago and was quite amazed at how easy it was to install applications. This method seemed easier to use than both windows and all other unix based operating systems I've ever used.

Dragging a file into an install folder is about as easy as it gets.

I do like the idea behind the ubuntu software center - but due to it almost always being out of date, it's usefulness is quite limited.

The functionality of apt-get is quite good as far as things go, but it's command line interface is quite unusable for non tech-savy users.

Comment: Because Mac apps are not real apps. You can do the same with Linux. Ever see a `*.py` script? Just place and run. You can also do this with EXE apps. Just drag and run.

Comment: Hmm good point, thanks for the nice comparison :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People who come from Windows expect everything to work like Windows does. People who come from Mac expect things to work like Mac does. Ubuntu is its own OS with advantages and disadvantages compared to Mac and Windows. The reality is that installing software is by no means difficult. You have the software center, apt-get, and also Synaptic, none of which are exceedingly difficult to use. Also, a quick google search can help you find out how to install pretty much anything you can't figure out yourself.

Comment: Personally, I think the fact that you have to search how to install every individual program is a bit of a smell

Comment: You don't, though, that's the thing. The vast majority of programs that mainstream users want are readily available in the software center. For the few that aren't, I don't think that a ten-second google search is cumbersome at all. Again, the OS has its drawbacks and advantages. Personally, I think this disadvantage (if you even call it that, which I don't) is far outweighed by the advantage of virtually never having to worry about a virus...

Comment: Hmm I do get your point. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

WOW, 
You think its hard to install an app now? You should have seen Ubuntu just a few generations ago having to manually install every app with the command line... its not super hard but you have to remember commands, and thats always been my issue with it... now it has the software center I can use Ubuntu more then just a little thing on a live CD... I actually have it installed on one of my partitions on my desktop now... and just for the simple fact it has the self install software center plus Steam....

To answer your question... I'm 99% sure Apple has that way of installing apps (dragging the app to your applications folder) patented so tough cookies ever seeing that here...